# How to handle the data concurrency?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, pdo

For instance , in my system i allow the user to create a list and add some information into the list eg. name , address, phone...

And after create the list, it will be inserted into database, and in the page the admin can delete the list

The problem is when user editing the list, the admin deleted the list, then what will happen?

The only way is to check the database again before the edit submit to the **database. However, If there are a lot of form, a lot of input, how can i check each field , there is a lot of job if i have to check every field that is concurrent.**

I am using php , mysql and pdo for query
Thank you

Comment: What is a "list". A set of rows? One rows with some fields? Are there other tables that "define" valid values in the list? How do you "edit" the list - do you load it in memory, modify it and save it in a single transaction or you separate load and save into separate transactions? Do you DELETE/INSERT or do you UPDATE the data that was modified?

Answer (score 0):

Well why wouldn't you simply check if the row exists in the corresponding table using it's primary key (id) ?

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, you cannot avoid that situation. While the user edits the form, the user cannot find out if the form has been deleted.

One solution would be to have a flag up once the user starts editing the records that should prevent anyone from editing at the same time/deleting at the same time. Once the user submits the form, then the flag should be back to original value, so that other users/admins can edit/delet those records.

There is a second solution of using a service and check from time to time in the user's page via ajax if the records are still there, but if you have alot of inputs, that can be a little cumbersome to implement.

Basicly, you need to create something that resembles a transaction, aka. lock the records that are being edited. Be very carefoul, since you can end up with alot of locked records. You need to implement a time in which the user needs to finalize the "transaction". If there are locked records beyond that time, unlock them automaticly. Also beware of the fact that the user might exceed that time and you need to handle that situation also, since you will end up in the same state as your original problem.

PS: also you need to beware of informations that have been edited while the user was editig also, since those informations would be lost. For the edit part, i think i would go for a hashing approach to check the state before editing with the state after editing. from this point on, it's up to you to decide what to do.

Comment: the flag is in database? set to 1 before any modify?